# SQLite SUM Problem, it does not sum correctly?

Tags: sqlite

Hello there and good morning!

I have a litte problem with the Database of the Time Tracking Software of our company.

The first problem: the time is in a dumb format. If someone works 7h 30m, the database writes 7,30 as value. So far so good. So I have to split the decimals, convert it to industrial time, and put it back together. So far so good. It works, if the value is under 10. Above 10, the value converts itself into INT. But that case should be intercepted by my code.

Here's the code:

```
 SELECT PersNr, Name, CASE WHEN substr(IstStd,3,1) LIKE ',' OR '.' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN (substr(IstStd,4,2)/60 NOT LIKE 0)  THEN ROUND((substr(IstStd,4,2))/60 + (substr(IstStd,1,2)),2) ELSE (IstStd) END)) ELSE (SUM(CASE WHEN (substr(IstStd,3,2)/60 NOT LIKE 0)  THEN ROUND((substr(IstStd,3,2))/60 + (substr(IstStd,1,1)),2) ELSE (IstStd) END)) END AS IstStd
 FROM ARCHIV_JOURNAL WHERE PersNr ='3041' AND Datum BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31'
```

As you can see in the first CASE, I check if the third character is `,` or `.` . The Code works fine, just not for 10h+.

Did I miss something? I'd appreciate any help with that.

If you need more information, just hit me back.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition:

```
WHEN substr(IstStd,3,1) LIKE ',' OR '.'
```

is not correct.
It is interpreted as:

```
WHEN (substr(IstStd,3,1) LIKE ',') OR ('.')
```

If you want to check if the 3d char is `','` or `'.'` you must do:

```
WHEN substr(IstStd,3,1) IN (',', '.')
```

Also in other parts of your code you use the operator `LIKE` when you should use `=` or `<>`.
Change to this:

```
SELECT PersNr, Name, 
  CASE 
    WHEN substr(IstStd,3,1) IN (',', '.') 
      THEN SUM(
             CASE 
               WHEN (substr(IstStd,4,2)/60 <> 0) THEN ROUND((substr(IstStd,4,2))/60 + (substr(IstStd,1,2)),2) 
               ELSE (IstStd) 
             END
           )
    ELSE SUM(
           CASE 
             WHEN (substr(IstStd,3,2)/60 <> 0) THEN ROUND((substr(IstStd,3,2))/60 + (substr(IstStd,1,1)),2) 
             ELSE (IstStd) 
           END
         )
  END AS IstStd
FROM ARCHIV_JOURNAL 
WHERE PersNr ='3041' AND Datum BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31'
```

Also when you divide integers the result is also an integer.
If you want the result of the division:

```
substr(IstStd,3,2))/60
```

to be a decimal number, then change it to:

```
substr(IstStd,3,2))/60.0
```

Comment: Hey forpas, sorry for the late reply. This was exactly the problem, thank you very much! This even solved Problems in my VBA export! Thanks so much!